# how to write a macro that will check for duplicate if?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I want to write a macro that will check if my if statements between the macros are unique

the statements between the macros are as follows

```
if([myString isEqualToString:@"one"]){
//do something
}
if ([myString isEqualToString:@"two"]){
//do two somethings
}
```

i want to enclose my ifs in something to make sure i dont have two ifs that check the same thing inside this block.

Is this possible ?

***edit***
I want my macro to do the following

start macro on object o
create a dictionary with key "o" and values
for every if statement between the macro brackets the "value" is checked inside the given array if its not there, push it in, otherwise give a #warning type macro that the value is already inside.

end macro and delete the aforementioned dictionary from memory.

Comment: It might be possible, but why bother?  Macros are there to remove tedium, not add complexity.

Comment: I need it ;), if i didnt need it, i wouldnt bother

Comment: Well I've never needed anything like that, so I am assuming you don't either.  Anyway, it's a free world.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Update your question with an example of what you trying to prevent.

Comment: @rmaddy please see edit

Answer (score 2):

This is the tip of a much bigger concern which is making sure you safely deal with string-like comparisons. The concern is good, but a macro is completely the wrong tool to try to fix it.

The correct tool is `switch`, which is exactly designed to deal with "I want to pick something out of a list." The compiler gives you all kinds of support for `switch`, including making sure you don't duplicate and that your checks are exhaustive. But `switch` doesn't work with strings. That's fine. It just means we have to turn our strings into an enum, and that's good for all kinds of things beyond just this particular concern.

The most important thing to do is to get rid of `@"one"` as quickly as you can, and turn it into something type-checkable, like an `OptionOne` enum case.

```
typedef enum _Options {
    OptionUnknown = 0, // This one must be zero; rest don't matter
    OptionOne,
    OptionTwo,
    OptionThree
} Options;


NSDictionary *options = @{@"one": @(OptionOne),
                          @"two": @(OptionTwo),
                          @"three": @(OptionThree)
                         };
```

Now it's easy to do what you want:

```
    switch ([options[myString] intValue]) {
        case OptionUnknown:
            NSLog(@"I don't know that option");
            break;
        case OptionOne:
            NSLog(@"Thanks for option 1");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Meh; who cares about these options?");
            break;
    }
```

Notice that I'm relying on ObjC nil-messaging here. `options[x]` is `nil` if `x` is not in the dictionary. `[nil intValue]` is 0 when returned in an integer-like context. So by making our "unknown" case 0, we can skip a lot of tedious and error-prone checking for whether the value is in the dictionary.

Comment: i need to do this for non checkable values, that i cannot turn into an enum, because it is not that simple

Comment: Then the problem is likely impossible (at least without trying to create an entire compiler out of the macro preprocessor, which people have done for fun, but is insanely fragile, complex, and slow). You will need to better frame your question in order to find a version that is possible. What you're describing is not a good fit for macros.